# How to use UpdateMany in mongoose

Tags: mongoose

I'm trying to use updateMany in Mongoose to reset a value to default. However, it keeps getting `500 Internal Server Error`. Where do I miss?

**Index.js**

```
app.put('/reset-match',  (req, res) => {
    Activity.updateMany({}, { $set: { color: "#ffffff" }},{upsert: true}, {multi: true}, (err,doc) => { 
        if(err) {res.status(400).send(err)}
        else res.status(205).send(doc)
    }); 

});
```

**Activity Model**

````
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const validator = require('validator');

const Activity = mongoose.model('activity', {
    name: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
        trim: true
    },
    icon: {
        type: String, 
        required: true,
        trim: true,
        validate(value) {
            if (!validator.isURL(value)) {
                throw new Error('URL is invalid');
            }
        }
    },
    color: {
        type: String, 
        default: '#fff'
    }
})


module.exports = Activity;
```

I expect the syntax of UpdateMany which works!
````

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're trying to call `updateMany()` function with too many parameters

```
Activity.updateMany({}, { $set: { color: "#ffffff" }},{upsert: true}, {multi: true}, (err,doc) => { ... })
```

Based on the [mongoose docs](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.updateMany), all options should be passed by one object, like so:

```
Activity.updateMany({}, { $set: { color: "#ffffff" }},{ upsert: true, limit: 20, skip: 50 }, (err,doc) => { ... })
```

Also, with the `updateMany()` function you don't need to use `multi: true` option. It make sense only when using `update()` func.

---

Try this code:

```
    Activity.updateMany({}, { $set: { color: "#ffffff" }}, { upsert: true }, (err, data) => { 
        if (err) {
            res.status(400).send(err)
        }
        res.send(data)
    })
```

Answer (score 0):

as mentioned in the [mongoose documents](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.updateMany/) this is how we do this:

`db.collection.updateMany(condition, update, options, callback function)`

so this is an example based on the docs:

```
async update_documents (req,res) => {

    // creating arguments
    let conditions = {};
    let update = {
        $set : {
      title : req.body.title,
      description : req.body.description,
      markdown : req.body.markdown
      }
    };
    let options = { multi: true, upsert: true };

    // update_many :)
    await YourCollection.updateMany(

      conditions, update, options,(err, doc) => {
        console.log(req.body);
        if(!err) {
          res.redirect('/articles');
        }
        else {
          if(err.name == "ValidationError"){
            handleValidationError(err , req.body);
            res.redirect('/new-post');
          }else {
            res.redirect('/');
          }
        }
      });
  }
```

this worked fine for me, I hope it helps :)